# Get Specific Columns in HasOne relationship in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

***Edit: Updated to hasOne in both classes***

I have two tables, `Store` and `Address`. One Store has one address and one address is associated with only one store.

In my `Store` model, I have a `hasOne` relationship.

```
public function store_address(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(Address::class, 'id', 'address_id');
}
```

And in `Address` model I have a `hasOne`:

```
public function store(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(Store::class, 'id', 'store_id');
}
```

Now I want to join these two tables using Eloquent with() with `select *` from `store` but want specific columns from the `address` table.

```
Store::where('user_id', $user_id)
      ->select(\DB::raw('*')
      ->with(['store_address' => function($query) {
          return $query->select(['distance_to_user as distance']);
      }])
      ->orderBy('distance');
```

However it's not returning the correct `distance` from the address table. How can I do that?

This is the error message I get:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distance' in 'order clause' (SQL: select *, from `store` where `store`.`user_id` = 12 and `store`.`deleted_at` is null order by `distance` asc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the structure of your tables

Addresses:

```
id | store_id| body | distance_to_user
----------------------------------------
 1 | 1       |China | 100
```

and for Stores:

```
id | name
--------------
 1 | Store_01
```

You should have Models like:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Address extends Model
{
    //

    public function store()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Store');
    }
}
```

and

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Store extends Model
{
    //
    public function address()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Address');
    }
}
```

now in your controller:

```
        public function index()
        {
            //return Store::with(['address' => function($q){
            //    $q->select('distance_to_user as distance','store_id');
            //    }])->get();


            return Store::leftJoin('addresses', 'addresses.store_id', '=', 'stores.id')


                 ->select('stores.id','stores.name','distance_to_user as distance')

                // OR use ->select('stores.*','addresses.id as address_id','distance_to_user as distance')

                ->orderBy('distance','Desc')

                ->get();
        }
```

Comment: Hi Ali, thank you for answering. I changed it to `hasOne` however it still seems that the `distance` column isn't available in my query. I updated the description with error message.

Comment: I don't know what is $query in this question. or what is your table structures and columns. so I have to guess.

try it with  ->orderBy('distance_to_user '); or return $query->select(['distance_to_user as distance']) ->orderBy('distance');

Comment: It still says column `distance_to_user` not found. I'm going to update `$query` to make it clear

Comment: so I need to know your tables's columns and your compelete code. But if you read my answer more accurate you will know what you can do that

Comment: Thanks very much Ali!